# how to find the email off all members in an office teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I dont know how to find all the emails of members in a team, i want to send an email to them all but i dont have the time to send it one by one so i was wondering if anyone knows how to find all emails at once?

Is there any way to do this efficently or? Can somebody help me?

I have tried to look into their website but i cant find anything helpful. If someone knows how to fix this please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iub5G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

@Mocko You could try to use a [bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots) to [fetch the email id's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet) of User in a team. You can also do this using Graph API to [get the members of a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).